# Ресайз изображений в Django

Tags: python, django, pillow

Нужно сделать отдельную страницу, на которой можно сделать ресайз изображения и задать ему высоту и ширину на свой выбор, не знаю, как это правильно реализовать, был бы премного благодарен

```
class Image(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, blank=True, null=True)
image_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

def clean(self):
    if (self.image == None and self.image_url == None) or (self.image != None and self.image_url != None):
        raise ValidationError('Image and ImageURL are both None or not None')

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('image_edit', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Comment: Как вариант вы можете обрабатывать изображения во фронтенде, используя готовые библиотеки, например, [Uppload](https://uppload.js.org). Возможно, для вас это будет проще

Comment: Мне нужно реализовать только с использованием Django

Comment: попробуй https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping